Is $13!+1$ or $13!+17$ a prime number?
I was investigating whether $13!+1$ and $13!+17$ are prime, and I'm curious about the best approach to determine primality for expressions like these. Given their large size, I’m wondering if there are any useful properties, theorems, or computational strategies that might simplify this check.
Would it be reasonable to use Wilson's Theorem or other modular arithmetic properties here, or is trial division by known primes the best route?

The answer to the title question is no

Please search for answers. We already have plenty of answers on general primality tests. Generally there are no  optimizations for numbers like that. Please don't duplicate said answers below.

What do you mean

If you have not the answer, plse dont write

$13!+1$ and $13! + 17$ have only $10$ decimal digits. This is not "large". Ask Wolfram Alpha or your favourite computer algebra system.
